# Almost sure weak convergence of conditional distributions

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, weak-convergence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ a probability space and $X_n, X, Y_n, Y$ defined on it taking values in $\mathbb{R}$ with $X_n \to X$ and $Y_n \to Y$ almost surely. Let $f_n, f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable functions satisfying
$$
f_n(X_n) \to f(X)
$$
almost surely. Further, suppose that the conditional distributions convergence almost surely weakly:
$$
\mathcal{L}(X_n \mid Y_n) \stackrel{w}{\to} \mathcal{L}(X \mid Y)
$$
in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, almost surely.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Does this imply that
$$
\mathcal{L}(f_n(X_n) \mid Y_n) \stackrel{w}{\to} \mathcal{L}(f(X) \mid Y)
$$
in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, almost surely?

$\textbf{Ansatz:}$ By the a generalised version of the continuous mapping theorem: If $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$, whenever $x_n \to x$ (continuous convergence), this holds. However, we have only the weaker assumption that $f_n(X_n) \to f(X)$ almost surely.

Comment: Can't u just use your "generalized version of the continuous mapping theorem" with $f_n(X_n)\chi_\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is the set which characterize your almost surely ($\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1$) ?

Comment: My guess is no. For almost every $Y_n(\omega)$, you have weak convergence of $X_n|Y_n(\omega)$ but $X_n|Y_n(\omega)$ and $X_n$ are potentially very different objects unless $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent. It seems difficult to learn something about the behavior of $f(X_n)|Y_n(\omega)$ if you only know about $f(X_n)$ unless $f$ is known to have certain properties.

Comment: @SacAndSac, this does not seem to work, for precisely the reason Galton pointed out that given $\omega$, $X_n$ and $X_n \mid Y_n(\omega)$ are very different objects (might not even have the same support). Thanks a lot for both of your comments still.